# How to solve this differential equation using Laplace transform?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, error-function

$$\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}+\dfrac{1}{2}y(t).t=\dfrac{1}{2} $$
My attempt : 
$$sY(s)-\dfrac{1}{2}Y'(s)=\dfrac{1}{2s} \implies Y(s)=\dfrac{1}{2s^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2s}Y'(s) $$ Now taking inverse laplace transform ..
$$ y(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}t.u(t)+\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}\left[ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{st}.Y'(s)ds\right] \,dt} $$
This underbraced integral i'm not able to solve, and the result has ***erfi(x)*** on it .
Please check my method and suggest something , thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the rule for the laplace transform of the inverse?

Comment: yeah i know @Abdel

Comment: consider this L{f′(t)}=sY(s)−f(0)

Comment: yeah i know this $$\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt} \rightarrow sY(s) $$ no initial conditions

Comment: you should thake f(0) equal to a constant C

Comment: Initial conditions are not given,so why should i consider it ? take a uncharged inductor for an example voltage across it is $$ V_{L}(t)=L \dfrac{di(t)}{dt} \implies V_{L}(s)=sLI(s) -s.\underbrace{\color{green}{I(0^{-})}}$$ , when it is charged $$I(0^{-}) \neq 0 $$ but when it is uncharged $$I(0^{-})=0$$ and lets forget about that can you help me to solve the integral

Comment: I didnt see the extra t next to y(t). This makes it much harder to solve with the laplace transform. Try a integrating factor instead. Try u(x) = 0.5*exp(0.25x^2)

Comment: yeah man i have already solved it with Integrating factor , but the assignment is to solve it with Laplace , nothing i can do to change that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56749/discussion-between-lelouch-d-light-and-abdel).